# Windows form RDLC report parameter in VB.NET

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms, report, rdlc

I am working on a Windows Application,Having trouble crating a RDLC Local report.

There are just 2 text boxes in the report, One is  Employee Name &  another one is address.

Everything is alright but I couldn't figure out how to pass RDLC Report variable & show its value in the Report text boxes or in the report .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check this post:

[Using the WinForms ReportViewer Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337089%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

**EDIT:**

Suppose you have a TextBox Control "TxtParameter" where you enter the employee Social Security Number.

```
    'Create a report parameter for the sales order number 
    Dim rpEmployeeSSN As New ReportParameter()
    rpEmployeeSSN.Name = "SocialSecurityNumber"
    rpEmployeeSSN.Values.Add(TxtParameter.Text)

    'Set the report parameters for the report
    Dim parameters() As ReportParameter = {rpEmployeeSSN}
    localReport.SetParameters(parameters)

    'Refresh the report
    reportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Comment: Hey @Nathan thanks for reply,

I have everything setup & also I can see Blank reportViewer when I run the application but could't pass the parameter to the rdlc.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
    *****Me.movingselectedTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LRCDBDataSet.movingselected)
    '+++++++++++++ passing parameter
    Dim repdate As Date = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
    Dim params(0), myparam As ReportParameter
     '++++++++++++++++++try2
    Dim myparams As New List(Of ReportParameter)
    myparam = New ReportParameter("rptcrdate", repdate)
    myparams.Add(myparam)
    'Report_Parameter_1
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(myparams)
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()*****
```

Comment: Consider adding more information in the answer. What does above piece of code do?